# Unified java api to integrate with multiple SMS gateways

Tags: java, spring-boot, sms-gateway

I'm building a common messaging service for our distributed micro services solution to send SMS notifications for the users using `Spring Boot`, this service should be configurable with `N` number of SMS gateways providers (`Nexmo`, `Twilio`, `Twizo`, etc.) according to our customers, so any suggestions for unified java api to handle this case instead of hacking the code every time I have a new SMS gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decouple your code with the SMS gateways by middleware such as message queue or JMS. You just push your SMS message to the MQ and then the SMS gateways act as comsumers to consume these messages.